# Simple Alert in React Native - function on press

Tags: javascript, react-native, alert

In React Native, we have the option to use an Alert to notify the user in a popup. These 'simple' Alerts can be composed with:

`Alert.alert('Hello world!')`

Which produces an Alert with a message, no title, and an "OK" button.

You can also make 2 or 3 button Alerts, which are composed as follows (2 button example):

```
Alert.alert(
  'Alert Title',
  'My Alert Msg',
  [
    {
      text: 'Ask me later', 
      onPress: () => console.log('Ask me later pressed')
    },
    {
      text: 'Cancel',
      onPress: () => console.log('Cancel Pressed'),
      style: 'cancel',
    },
    {
      text: 'OK', 
      onPress: () => console.log('OK Pressed')
    },
  ],
  {cancelable: false},
);
```

Notice here you have the options for an `onPress` function for the buttons

What I am wondering is if I can apply an `onPress` for the first case, when 'OK' is pressed, but there is no example (or any details really!) in [the official docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/alert)

Perhaps it is not (yet) possible. Can anyone confirm or deny?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can create an `Alert` with only one button. You can then decide what happens when you press `OK`.

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/alert

> ## iOS
>
> On iOS you can specify any number of buttons. Each button can
>   optionally specify a style, which is one of 'default', 'cancel' or
>   'destructive'.
>
> ## Android
>
> On Android at most three buttons can be specified. Android has
>   a concept of a neutral, negative and a positive button:
>
> - If you specify one button, it will be the 'positive' one (such as 'OK')
> - Two buttons mean 'negative', 'positive' (such as 'Cancel', 'OK')
> - Three buttons mean 'neutral', 'negative', 'positive' (such as 'Later',
>     'Cancel', 'OK')

So if you only want one button then you can do something like this.

```
Alert.alert(
  'Alert Title',
  'My Alert Msg', // <- this part is optional, you can pass an empty string
  [
    {text: 'OK', onPress: () => console.log('OK Pressed')},
  ],
  {cancelable: false},
);
```

If you use `Alert.alert('Hello world!')` without passing any options to it then there is no way to define what happens when you press `OK` the only way to do that is to do something like I have show above. If you want it to look the same on the screen, then just pass an empty string for the message. Both the title and the message can be empty strings, though you probably don't want both to be that at the same time.

Comment: Perfect! React Native should really leave an example like this in the docs... also, the alert title can be an empty string as well.

Comment: I am glad it is working. I think it is inferred from the fact that you are passing an array of buttons to the alert. It's always worth trying different things to see if it works.

Answer (score 6):

You can create like this if no want to use title

```
Alert.alert(
     '',
     'Are you sure you want to delete?'+notificationId,  
     [
        {text: 'Cancel', onPress: () => console.log('Cancel Pressed'), style: 'cancel'},
        {text: 'OK', onPress: () => console.log('OK Pressed')},
     ],
     { cancelable: false }
)
```